# Is there a way to update, not overwrite, worker_env for a Dask YarnCluster within a script?

Tags: dask

In my configuration file for Dask-Yarn, i.e. `~.config/dask/yarn.yaml`, I am setting the worker environment variable as follows:

```
yarn:

  name: dask                 # Application name
  queue: default             # Yarn queue to deploy to
  deploy-mode: remote        # The deploy mode to use (either remote or local)
  environment: /dask_yarn.tar.gz          # Path to conda packed environment
  user: ''                     # The user to submit the application on behalf of

  worker:                   # Specifications of worker containers
    count: 0                # Number of workers to start on initialization
    restarts: -1            # Allowed number of restarts, -1 for unlimited
    env: {"ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR": "/usr/hdp/lib"}                 # A map of environment variables to set on the worker
```

Now, in my script, I want to set another environment variable in my workers that is derived in the script, such as,

```
cluster = YarnCluster(worker_env={"env_var": env_val})
```

where `env_val` is derived in this script before the above statement. But this statement, will override the configuration specified earlier in `~.config/dask/yarn.yaml`. I don't want to hard-code `ARROW_LIBHDFS_DIR` in my script, neither can I set this variable in `~.config/dask/yarn.yaml` since it is derived during script execution. So is there a way to just update the worker environment in the script without overwriting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not an option with the constructor, but you can do this by accessing dask's config right now:

```
import dask
# Get the existing worker_env field (use `.copy` so as not to mutate it)
worker_env = dask.config.get("yarn.worker.env", {}).copy()
# Add a new environment variable
worker_env["env_var"] = env_var
# Create your cluster
cluster = YarnCluster(worker_env=worker_env, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks @jiminy_crist!